# How to get multiple return values from python script without printing it in batch

Tags: python, batch-file, jenkins

Im writing a batch script that calls a python script, and then calling a jenkins URL.
I want to pass the jenkins some results from the python script (string results),
I dont want to use the print to a tmp file and then load it to a batch vars,
because in the script I sometimes print something like "File is opened, program closed. please try again!"

python gen_build_summary_info.py

set CORE = ????

set BUILD = ?????

java -jar y:\DTS_tests_run\Compiler\clean_up\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://***** build new_build_summary_report -p BUILD=%BUILD% -p CORE=%CORE%

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: maybe shell out to `java -jar ...` from the python script? or rewrite the thing in powershell and avoid python?

Comment: is it possible to call java from python?

Comment: sure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: thanks alot!
I have used this:
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'jenkins-cli.jar', '-s http://*** build new_build_summary_report'])

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass the data through pipe.

In your `.bat` file:

```
python xxx.py | java -jar xxx.jar
```

Print the result in Python and then read it in Java. You can use something like JSON to encode multiple values together.

2. Just get rid of the batch file and invoke your java program directly in the Python script.

One possible solution is using `subprocess` library to run Java, and send the result by command line arguments, like:

```
import subprocess
result='12345'
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', '...(your program)', result])
```

3. Use a RPC library like [jsonrpc](http://json-rpc.org/). Register a function in Java and call it in Python.